# Can a bounty simply not be awarded?

Tags: discussion, bounty

The last couple of times I've set bounties on my questions they've generated what are, at best, hints. In both cases those hints pointed me in a general direction, and after much digging I was able to form a proper solution which I then posted as an answer.

However, absent of an actual *productive* answer from someone else the bounty is going to get auto-awarded to the answer-equivalent of "have you tried turning it off and back on again?".

Why is there not an option to simply *not award the bounty* and let those points evaporate into the ether?

What about in the case that absolutely *no* useful answers are posted? Should someone be rewarded for simply throwing their hat into the ring?

Comment: Related: [Explicit “do not award bounty” button](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166172/explicit-do-not-award-bounty-button)

Comment: @animuson status-declined? sad-face...

Answer (score 10):

> Why is there not an option to simply not award the bounty and let those points evaporate into the ether?

Because it's open to abuse whereby people refuse to award a bounty to a quality and correct answer out of spite.

> What about in the case that absolutely no useful answers are posted? Should someone be rewarded for simply throwing their hat into the ring?

In theory if the answer aren't useful they wouldn't have a score above one; they'd get downvoted.  In practice, bad answers do get upvotes, which is unfortunate.

So both options have problems.  SE made a judgement call.

Comment: Aww... spite is a solid 80% of my motivation in life. `:I`

Answer (score 1):

FYI, a Bounty will expire if no worthy answers are posted. I have had that happen. You do not get the points back, and they are not awarded. In one case it seem that an answer was posted in an attempt to collect the bounty be default. I believe this process could be improved, from increasing the bounty in an effort to attract more attention, to flat out denying it when perhaps multiple (say 3) users agree it does not solve the issue. But it does cause more review work in such a case, not a good thing.

Comment: Unfortunately, the person who posted the bounty doesn't get to choose whether an answer is _not worthy_... if the community upvotes that's it.

Comment: Ah, but they should get one vote, a perfect example of possible viable change. OP is obligated to award the bounty or it will be automatically given an appropriately scored answer, right or wrong.

Comment: That's the whole point. The OP seems to be of the opinion that the person offering the bounty should be able to _explicitly deny_ the bounty to an answer which was not, to their mind, worthy of the reward. I've encountered this myself and I whole-heartedly agree. Even a half-bounty is sometimes undeserved.

Comment: I believe we are in agreement then.